# Postman GET request with ipv6

Tags: http, request, postman, ipv6

How can I make a `GET` request in `postman` with `ipv6` address?

I have tried some examples below:

```
http://[fe80::e4ac:e9ff:fec9:f5d7]
http://[fe80::e4ac:e9ff:fec9:f5d7]:80/tpw/v1/moRtgRule/1
http://[fe80::e4ac:e9ff:fec9:f5d7%2]:80/tpw/v1/moRtgRule/1
http://[fe80::e4ac:e9ff:fec9:f5d7%252]:80/tpw/v1/moRtgRule/1
http://[fe80::e4ac:e9ff:fec9:f5d7%25host0]:80/tpw/v1/moRtgRule/1
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8qo5.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not answering your question, just giving random advice: It's best to leave usage link-local addresses to protocols that are made for it, and use global or ULA addresses for everything else. And if you can use hostnames instead of address literals.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of syntax?

Comment: The syntax is the same, just use routable IPv6 addresses instead of link-local

Answer (score 4):

Postman is an [Electron](https://electronjs.org/) app. Electron apps are built on Chromium, which is a web browser. Web browsers such as Chromium [intentionally](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=70762) do not have the ability to connect to link-local IPv6 addresses.

To work around the issue, connect to the remote machine's global or ULA address or its hostname.